# Xfce4 menu is not showing all applications

Tags: xfce, menu, ubuntu-studio, whisker

In my Whiskermenu pre-installed applications are not shown. After a reinstall of for example Gimp Whisker could not find it either. The `xfce4-popup-applicationswindow` too did not show them.

I tried resetting by `pkill xconfd` and deleting xfce4 in `~/.config/` and a restart.

I use UbuntuStudio 16.04 which is like Xubuntu but with a custom theme and some software for music and art creation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delete the file `/home/username/.config/menus/xfce-applications.menu`. This file is created when you use the menu-editor. After deleting the file all applications will show up in the menu, but `Favorites` will be empty, you can easily repopulate by adding favorites. Don't use the menu-editor, it always leads to loss of menu-entries.

If you can't open Thunar from the menu, open terminal with `Ctrl+Alt+T` and use command `rm ~/.config/menus/xfce-applications.menu`

Comment: "Don't use the menu-editor, it always leads to loss of menu-entries." - Sounds pretty dysfunctional. Is there a bug report for this somewhere, or is it just one of those nuggets of developer wisdom that never made it to the official documentation?

Comment: @TimStaley It's just my experience, after running in the same problem I just stopped using the menu-editor, it is not really necessary to use it, the menu is very functional. I'm not a developer, just a beginner...